# Is there a way to show a font that is not supported by a browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I want to use a font called BPreplay and I'm guessing it's not supported by at least one major browser, if not all of them.

Is there a way using css or javascript/jquery or some other way to allow the browser to support and use the font on my website so that my users will see the font that I want them too?

Thanks!

Comment: Browsers support most fonts, but it depends on the font format.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@font-face` property to use a custom font.
Each browser needs a diferent type of font. You can read more [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) and find fonts compatible with all browsers [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface)

Answer (score 2):

Have you investigated Cufon or sIFR? Cufon is located at http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/ and sIFR is at http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr/

Both allow for you to serve up the font you want.

Comment: I would discourage the use of sIFR - I used it for awhile and switched to Cufon soon. Cufon is the better option because it makes do without the need for Flash support, and makes use of the `<canvas>` element in HTML5 instead.

p/s: Make sure you read the terms and conditions of using the font.

Comment: I use Cufon with all my sites including Wordpress, to try and keep fonts and their sizes uniform across browsers and their versions. Or to make the client who just can't get enough of the Park Avenue font in all caps for his business name a happy little clam.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Google Web Fonts? http://www.google.com/webfonts

Comment: I don't recommend it. At least here, the text is hidden for a little before the font loads, i think it's ugly.

Comment: Plus, anti-aliasing on Google Web Fonts isn't too nice.

Answer (score 0):

the `@font-face` css property allows you to specify a custom font by hosting it on your server and then specifying the url. You can implement it something like

```
@font-face {  
    font-family: 'BPrelay';  
    src: url('fontname.ttf');
}  

p { 
    font-family: BPrelay, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
```

You can also use services like [Google web fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) or [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) to handle hosting and liscensing for you.

You can also [provide a fallback to a local file](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design-tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-font-face/) if the user has it - to save on bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

I find cufon a lot more elegant than @font-face - anti-aliasing is way crisper. Yeah, it's using javascript to control styling, which really should be left to css only, but hey, it works well, and most people couldn't give two stuffs about web standards